# What association should I create in edmx file in Visual Studio?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, diagram, edmx

I have 3 tables in database and I've added them to the edmx file in Visual Studio, and so that I can access them by `Offers`, `Schools`, and I can access their fields by `Offers[i].OfferName`, `Offers[i].OfferId`, `Schools[i].SchoolId`, `Schools[i].SchoolName`, etc.

The 1st one is the **offer list**:

    `╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║ # ║ Offer Id   ║ Offer Name  ║
    ╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║ 1 ║ 1          ║ Offer 1     ║
    ║ 2 ║ 2          ║ Offer 2     ║
    ║ 3 ║ 3          ║ Offer 3     ║
    ╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝`

The 2nd one is the **school list**:

    `╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║ # ║ School Id  ║ School Name ║
    ╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║ 1 ║ 1          ║ School 1    ║
    ║ 2 ║ 2          ║ School 2    ║
    ║ 3 ║ 3          ║ School 3    ║
    ╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝`

The 3rd one is a **OfferSchoolMapping** table:

    `╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║ # ║ Offer Id   ║ School Id   ║
    ╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║ 1 ║ 1          ║ 1           ║
    ║ 2 ║ 1          ║ 2           ║
    ║ 3 ║ 2          ║ 1           ║
    ║ 4 ║ 2          ║ 2           ║
    ║ 5 ║ 2          ║ 3           ║
    ║ 6 ║ 3          ║ 1           ║
    ╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝`

Now I want to create association among the 3 tables, so that I can access them via something like this:
`Schools[i].Offers`, `Offers[i].Schools`. For example, I want:
`Schools[1].Offers` = 

`Offer 1
Offer 2`

`Offers[1].Schools` = 

`School 1
School 2
School 3`

**So what association should I create via Visual studio?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schools and Offers tables are in many-to-many relationship. In EF designer, set-up association between your entities and set `Multiplicity` to `* (Collection)` at both ends. Next, set `Association Set Name` to your mapping table `OfferSchoolMapping`.
Generally, your set-up should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Where is the mapping table? Should I delete the mapping table then? The data tables have already been in database...

Comment: Yes, mapping table should not be present in the designer.

Comment: How does Entity Framework know which database table is the mapping table then? Will it create another new mapping table instead of using the already existing one?

Comment: If you are generating your Model from the Database (Database-first approach), you should automatically get what you want (it will recognize many-to-many between those two tables). If you want to create your Model using designer and then create your Database (Model-first approach), you should Association Set Name to the desired name of your Mapping table and it will create corresponding table in the database. Hope this helps.

Comment: Finally I got it the association should be attached to the primary key field.